# How to query distinct on a joined column?

Tags: sqlalchemy

This is the code, I would like to have UserCheckpoint.checkpoint to be distincts. Meaning all the UserCheckpoints queried should all have distinct Checkpoint objects.

```
friends_ucp = (db.session.query(UserCheckpoint).
               join(UserCheckpoint.checkpoint).
               filter(radius_cond).
               filter(Checkpoint.demo == False).
               filter(UserCheckpoint.user_id.in_(friends))
               )
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please, either add your solution as an answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved this using `group_by()`

Comment: Could you provide an example?